# can a valid mysql query fail if after i managed to connect?

Tags: php, mysql

After i have managed to connect to mysql db with php, can a valid query fail because of internet connection lost or somthing like that? Or is it safe to say that a valid query will succeed?

```
 $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","..."..."",".....");
if($con)
$a1=  mysqli_query($con, "insert into ....(valid query)");
```

can the query fail if $con is true?

Comment: Thats why we use transaction.

Comment: Transactions don't guarantee the queries within them will succeed; they guarantee that either all of them will or none of them will.

Answer (score 0):

Queries can always fail. It would be foolish to assume otherwise - who's to say someone hasn't dropped the table/database since it was last run? :)

You should always add error handling to your queries and make sure display_errors is off so you don't leak sensitive details if something does go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My take on your question

When you run your query, your query is sent to the server for processing.

Once the server receives your query it runs it and attempts to send the result back to you.

2 scenarios :

1) You loose your connection before your query makes it to the server - in that case your query will not run.

2) You loose your connection after your query makes it to the server, in which case the server will run the query but you will not be available to receive the response. Your query will still run.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is valid, certain things can cause a query to fail.

- If your database is located on a separate server and that server goes down, then you will lose MySQL functions.
- If your MySQL server is locked up or crashes on its own, in the middle of a script, it will fail.
- As George mentioned, if the MySQL db is altered in any way that may cause the query to fail (but this assumes the query is now invalid).